# How to set different value for debug and release mode in CMakeLists.txt without using CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE?

Tags: debugging, cmake, compilation, release

I'm willing to set different macro for debug mode and release mode like that:

```
if (current_is_debug) 
    add_compile_definitions(TAPD)
else()
    add_compile_definitions(TAP)
endif()
```

I think I shall not set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in CMakeLists.txt because I'm to set compile mode when building, i.e.

```
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
```

So Is there anyway to set different macro for different compile mode ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The generic way for configuration-specific settings is using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). In you case it could be `add_compile_definitions($<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,TAPD,TAP>`)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Nice! That's exactly what I want.